# PHP: Get string from Python dictionary like String

Tags: php

I have a string like:

```
{"Url":"http://localhost","DBName":"John_db","DBUser":"admin","Pass":"a"}
```

Now using this string I want URL, DBname, DBuser and pass them to separate variables like:

```
$DBName =  'John_db';
$DBUser =  'admin';
$Url    =  'http://localhost';
$Pass   = 'a';
```

I am new to PHP, and can't find any solution to achieve this, can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to split each one into individual variables. You could just decode that JSON into an array or object:

```
$str = '{"Url":"http://localhost","DBName":"John_db","DBUser":"admin","Pass":"a"}';
$arr = json_decode( $str, true );
```

Now you have an associative array containing all of the variables:

```
Array(
  [ Url ] => "http://localhost",
  [ DBName ] => "John_db",
  ...
)
```

If you don't specify the second parameter to `json_decode()`, you'll get a regular object:

```
$obj = json_decode( $str );
echo $obj->Url; // http://localhost
echo $obj->DBName; // John_db
```

References -

- [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort!, Now i have one issue, in the string the key has a white space, like {"DB Name":"John_db"}. that time I can't take a value from the $obj, do you have any solution for that?

Comment: In that case you should make an associative array (my first example) by passing `true` to `json_decode()`. Then you'll be able to access that value by using: `$arr[ "DB Name" ]`.

Answer (score 2):

"This string" is JSON object. Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) to get array with all values and then get it from there.

```
$str = '{"Url":"http://localhost","DBName":"John_db","DBUser":"admin","Pass":"a"}';
$out = json_decode( $str, true );
```

and `$out` ends like:

```
Array
(
    [Url] => http://localhost
    [DBName] => John_db
    [DBUser] => admin
    [Pass] => a
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ar = json_decode( '{"Url":"http://localhost","DBName":"John_db","DBUser":"admin","Pass":"a"}', 1 );
foreach ($ar as $k => $a) {
   $$k = $a;
}
```

Now you should have your vars filled.

Working code here: http://codepad.org/Do9ixqfN

Comment: With list you have to be sure that JSON has every elements in the right position. You can't be sure about this.

Comment: True true true.. missed that!

Comment: I suppose you could sort the array before using `list()`, but that's over complicating things...

Comment: You're right, but JSON can miss a param and we return to the start of the problem, again :P

Comment: That's true... I suppose if you can't guarantee that all the values will always be there then it really isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode function like this:

```
<?
$string = '{"Url":"http://localhost","DBName":"John_db","DBUser":"admin","Pass":"a"}';
$array = json_decode( $string, true );

print_r($array);
?>
```

[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/TayMHqJt)

Answer (score 0):

That string is a JSON object and you can use json_decode to convert that string into an associative array.

Comment: A little more explanation and perhaps some examples would really help to improve this answer.

Comment: @Lix, by the time i posted and started to expand, many others answered as well.